# why Pyinstaller3.5 package openpyxl error

Tags: python, python-3.x

pyinstaller3.5/python3.5/openpyxl 2.3.5

run pyinstaller -F test.py

If no import op

there is error:

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30865792/openpyxl-library-jdcal-error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [openpyxl library - jdcal error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30865792/openpyxl-library-jdcal-error)

Answer (score 0):

if no import openpyxl there is no error.
but if import openpyxl